# TypeScript: the Map instance iterating

Tags: javascript, typescript

I learn TypeScript. I expected my JavaScript (ES6) code will work for TypeScript too. But I get the unexpected result...

```
const dict = new Map([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]);

for (let pair of dict) {
    // The 'pair'  is an array: [key, value].
    console.log(`${pair[0]} = ${pair[1]}`);
}
```

The preceding code works in Google Chrome 61.0. But when I copy it into the left text editor of [TypeScript online editor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) then I get an invalid result: generated JavaScript code doesn't do what I expected.

Also I see the error for `dict` using:

> Type 'Map' is not an array type or a string type.
>   const dict: Map

Why does it happen?

Comment: In the [**typescript online editor**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), the `for...of` loop used to loop the map is converted into `for(var i = 0; i < ***.length...`. Since map don't have a property `length` (like an array or string), that warning is thrown.

Comment: Use a `foreach`, it is a nice way to iterate over map and it will give you value, index, map refer nice in this order.

Comment: Playground target is es5, hence the results